# Qt slot connected successful but wasn't fired

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qtcpserver

I try to call slot of my class via `newConnection()` signal of `QTcpServer` class. `connect()` function returns `true`, but the slot weren't executed.

Here's what i made:

```
class server : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    server();

    QTcpServer *srv;
    void run();

public slots:
    void handleClient();
}
```

Bind the slot:

```
void server::run()
{
    srv = new QTcpServer();

    bool status = connect(srv, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(handleClient()));

    // status contains true now

    srv->listen(QHostAddress::Any, port);
}
```

Slot's body:

```
void server::handleClient()
{
        /* This code is not being executed */
        qDebug() << "zxc";
        QMessageBox msg;
        msg.setText("zxc");
        msg.exec();
}
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Looks ok. Have you called qmake after adding Q_OBJECT macro to your class?

Comment: Check the return value of `listen`, if it is returning `false`, please add the string in `errorString()` to the question.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz, yes i made this.

Comment: @skyhisi, it returns true.

Comment: Are you sure you connect to the server? How? The port number should correspond to the opened one, btw.

Comment: @vahancho, yes i sure. I caught `connected()` signal at the client side for `QTcpSocket` successful, so client isn't cause i think. Port numbers are similar too..:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're doing wrong try adding `public` in the inheritance line (`: public QObject`).

The following code works for me:

**server.hpp**

```
#ifndef _SERVER_HPP_
#define _SERVER_HPP_
#include <QtNetwork>

class Server : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Server();
  private slots:
    void handleClient();
  private:
    QTcpServer* mServer;
};
#endif
```

**server.cpp**

```
#include "server.hpp"

Server::Server() : mServer(new QTcpServer())
{
  connect(mServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(handleClient()));
  mServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 10000);
}

void Server::handleClient()
{
  while (mServer->hasPendingConnections())
  {
    QTcpSocket* skt = mServer->nextPendingConnection();
    skt->write("READY\n");
    skt->waitForReadyRead(5000);
    qDebug() << skt->readAll();
    skt->write("OK\n");
    skt->waitForBytesWritten();
    skt->close();
    skt->deleteLater();
  }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "server.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  Server srv;
  return app.exec();
}
```